# accessing CiviCRM dashboard link for first time fails

Tags: wordpress

Virgin Wordpress Install - The install seemed to go fine - all green.
Clicking the CiviCRM link in the dashboard link gives DB Error: unknown error
[image: Dashboard]

Answer (score 1):

I did a re-install. Curiously, when I downloaded the instal again, there were more files. Anyway, I have now moved the problem on to getting a white screen. I guess that's progress. Will close this question.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know what the problem is without enabling debugging.  Go to http://yoursite.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/setting/debug&reset=1 and see if you can turn on enable debugging.  That will display the actual query and MySQL error when you get this again.

Comment: This error is shown now at the top when I click the CiviCRM link in the Wordpress dashboard...Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in /home/cjcuser/55plusclub.canberrajazzclub.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php on line 182

Comment: No clue on this, but at least it might help others who could help.

Comment: and also now...  Notice: ob_end_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (1) in /home/cjcuser/55plusclub.canberrajazzclub.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3297 Notice: ob_end_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (1) in /home/cjcuser/55plusclub.canberrajazzclub.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3297